# Meaning of expected value of ratio $\mathbb{E}\bigg(\frac{S_t}{S_{t-1}}\bigg)=1$?

Tags: expected-value

I'm wondering what does it mean for the expected value of a ratio to equal one:

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg(\frac{S_t}{S_{t-1}}\bigg)=1$$

and if this is some general property of the expectation of some ratio.

This appears in the context of the Cox, Ross and Rubinstein options pricing model. I've seen a claim that this means that the "price doesn't change on average".

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. one of the standard approaches to pricing   derivatives  is to assume the discounted stock price (or any ratio of two financial assets) is a martingale $\mathbb {E} \left( X_t | X_{t-1}\dots X_{t-s} \right)= X_{t-s}$ see eg http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~magdon/courses/cf/notes/martingale.pdf (theorem 1.7, though they don't define martingale properly)... You had better ask your question on quantitative finace or the wilmott forum

Answer (score 5):

This is *not* a general property of ratios. This is claiming two things: first, the time dynamics are 'balanced,' and that the balancing is with respect to multiplication, not addition. Contrast to $\mathbb{E}(S_t-S_{t-1})=0$.

Note that this is balancing, not symmetry. If the price can either double or halve, then this equality is true only if the price doubles a third of the time and halves two thirds of the time.

(It also implies that $S_{t-1}$, and thus presumably $S_t$, can never be 0.)

Comment: So balancing means that one merely picks some unbounded variables in $S_t$ so that the expectation of the ratio equals one? My reference suggests that one should  "select $a,b$ in $p=\frac{b}{b-a}$", $p$ being a variable in the expectation of $S_t$.

Comment: That depends on what perspective you're taking. If you have a complete model for how $S_t$ depends on $S_{t-1}$, you can determine what that model implies about the expected value of the ratio between the two of them. If it's true that the price doesn't change on average (which we often expect for financial products), then that constrains the possible set of models--allowing us to complete models on incomplete info.

Answer (score -1):

If we have a stochastic process $X_1, X_2, ...$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$, then $\frac{X_t}{X_{t-1}}$ for $t = 2, 3, ...$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ that shows that ratio of a random variable in the sto process to the previous random variable.

'$E[\frac{X_t}{X_{t-1}}] = 1$' means that throughout the whole sto process, on average the ratio between one random variable and the one before it is 1.

So the stochastic process $\frac{X_2}{X_1}, \frac{X_3}{X_2}, ...$ has the same mean. If the $\frac{X_n}{X_{n-1}}$'s are integrable, then

If we have $E[\frac{X_n}{X_{n-1}} | \mathscr F_m] = \frac{X_m}{X_{m-1}}$ for some m < n and $\mathscr F_m$ is some filtration, then $\{\frac{X_n}{X_{n-1}}\}_{n \ge 2}$ is a martingale.